# Problem to save related tables 'in one go' in blazor server with EntityFrameworkCore + mysql

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, blazor, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I'm using Blazor server with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and have this problem with saving tables with complex relations, when doing it all at once.

Example:
So lets say entity 'Country' has collection of entity 'City' and each 'City' has collection of entity 'Street'.

```
public class Country
{
                public Guid Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
 
public class City
{
                public Guid Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; }
}
 
public class Street
{
                public Guid Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Table, that joins Countries and Cities:

```
CountryCityId CountryId CityId
```

Table, that joins the above table line to Street:

```
CountryCityId StreetId
```

**What is working fine:**
Create City, add List of Streets to it and save City:

```
unitOfWork.RepositoryOf<City>().Add(City);
await unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
```

Add City to Country list of Cities and another save:

```
Country.Cities.Add(City);
unitOfWork.RepositoryOf<Country>().Update(Country);
await unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
```

**What does not work:**
Create City, add List of Streets to it, then add it:

```
City.Add(Streets);
Country.Cities.Add(City);
```

and save it all at once:

```
unitOfWork.RepositoryOf<Country>().Update(Country);
await unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
```

I get an error like:

```
efcore Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

For me it seems like orm is trying to insert rows with foreign keys, before it inserts the rows, where foreign keys should point.
Any clues ? Is there anything obvious, that I should take a look at ?

Comment: Work with entities as with objects. Create one Country, then add to Country Cities and add Strees to Cities. Then just add one Country to DbContext and SaveChanges.

Comment: Exactly this approach causes the error for me : /

Comment: I do not see this approach in your sample.

Comment: I just modified it a bit to show it. I already have Country, so I create City; I add List of streets to City; I add City to Country.Cities. Then at the end I save Country. Then I have the error. If I split it into 2 saves : First save City, then Save Country it works.

Comment: Do not call SaveChanges every time. Do not call Update.

Comment: What worked for me: first Add City to Country.Cities. Then in second step edit the specific member of Country.Cities, by adding Streets.

Comment: As said, you can build an entire country with cities and their streets and only then add the country and save changes. Why don't you try that?

Answer (score 0):

#### Typical implementation

A typical implementation would look like the following and would use a foreign key property on its `Street` entity (referencing `City.Id`):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class City
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Street> Streets { get; set; } = new HashSet<Street>();
    }
 
    public class Street
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid CityId { get; set; } // <-- foreign key, referencing City.Id
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Street> Streets { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So68982686";
            var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

            optionsBuilder
                .UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var city = new City { Name = "Berlin" };
                city.Streets.Add(new Street { Name = "Potsdamer Platz" });
                context.Cities.Add(city);

                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var city = context.Cities
                    .Include(c => c.Streets)
                    .First();
                
                Trace.Assert(city.Name == "Berlin");
                Trace.Assert(city.Streets.Count == 1);
                Trace.Assert(city.Streets.First().Name == "Potsdamer Platz");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following SQL gets generated:

```sql
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE DATABASE `So68982686`;

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `Cities` (
          `Id` char(36) COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_Cities` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
      ) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (31ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `Streets` (
          `Id` char(36) COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `CityId` char(36) COLLATE ascii_general_ci NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_Streets` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_Streets_Cities_CityId` FOREIGN KEY (`CityId`) REFERENCES `Cities` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
      ) CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (25ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE INDEX `IX_Streets_CityId` ON `Streets` (`CityId`);

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[@p0='08d996c3-9074-4359-8d0f-e9df957a75d4', @p1='Berlin' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `Cities` (`Id`, `Name`)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1);

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[@p2='08d996c3-9080-47d8-8cb3-5b8ee8c7e720', @p3='08d996c3-9074-4359-8d0f-e9df957a75d4', @p4='Potsdamer Platz' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `Streets` (`Id`, `CityId`, `Name`)
      VALUES (@p2, @p3, @p4);

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.0-dev initialized 'Context' using provider 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql:6.0.0-rc.1' with options: SensitiveDataLoggingEnabled DetailedErrorsEnabled ServerVersion 8.0.25-mysql

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `t`.`Id`, `t`.`Name`, `s`.`Id`, `s`.`CityId`, `s`.`Name`
      FROM (
          SELECT `c`.`Id`, `c`.`Name`
          FROM `Cities` AS `c`
          ORDER BY `c`.`Id`
          LIMIT 1
      ) AS `t`
      LEFT JOIN `Streets` AS `s` ON `t`.`Id` = `s`.`CityId`
      ORDER BY `t`.`Id`
```

The code works as expected and you can save as many different entities in one go as you wish.

---

In case the same `Street` can be part of multiple `City` entities, meaning you want a many-to-many relationship, I can post you some sample code for that scenario as well.